# Why am I getting the GRUB screen?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Okay, so I recently decided to switch motherboards, and I succeeded. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is currently my version, and it's set as my default OS. I dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu currently, and I feel like I'm on the brink of removing Ubuntu all together. I only installed to learn something new, but I can't seem to get it to start again. When I get to the GRUB screen I tried putting in *boot* but it says no kernel loaded, and I haven't been able to get any response out of it. I can currently only boot to Windows 10 after I select the proper drive on my boot selection. Ubuntu is completely separate from Windows. Windows is on a completely different drive. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you destroyed some of zhe boot informations as you changed out your mainboard.

But to help futher as this state we need a bit mor info about your system. I ask this as camment and ajust this answer as we pass through the questions.

all other feel free to help or suggest your own answer.

Comment: We need to know a little bit more about your partionioning.  Please post your drives and their partioning.  e.g sda1 300MiB ESP FAT32  sda2 500 GiB windows NTFS  sdb1 100 MiB BOOT ext2  sdb2 20 GiB linux ext4  sdb3 400 GiB home BTFS  sdb4 4 GiB swap